# Bad visualization of games in macos

Tags: graphics, fullscreen, games, macos

I'm having a problem when playing games on full screen or windowed games on macOS. The first photo I clicked is an example of how it shows the screen when trying to play albion online. The second photo is how it shows the screen when I try to take a screenshot using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>. I guess is a problem of configuration and not of the screen, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Need more information.  Is this a MacBook (bad display cable)?  Which programs do these distortions happen to?  Can you clarify that the first photo is a picture from your phone and not a screenshot?

Comment: What model of Mac is this? My first thought is a graphics hardware problem.

Comment: It's a macbook pro 2018, 15 inch, 6 core with radeon graphics.